# Up button leads to home activity instead of parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

I'm a total newbie with Android and I have a weird situation I don't understand: I have a simple application with 3 activities:

- A RootActivity in which I check whether the user is logged in. If he is, I display the interface normally. If not, I'm starting the OnboardingActivity.
- An OnboardingActivity that contains a small video demo of the application, a first-interaction-then-sign-up button, and a sign in button. And when the user clicks the sign in button, it starts the LoginActivity
- The LoginActivity contains a simple login form and a login button, plus a toolbar with a back button.

And when the user taps the back button in the LoginActivity, I want to send him back to then OnboardingActivity, to give him the option to watch the demo or interact-and-signup.

So I configured my 3 activities as such:

```
<activity android:name=".RootActivity">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".OnboardingActivity" />
<activity
     android:name=".LoginActivity"
     android:label="Login"
     android:parentActivityName=".OnboardingActivity">
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.derbigum.approofreferences.OnboardingActivity" />
</activity>
```

In the RootActivity's onCreate, I have the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_references)

    authentication = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    currentUser = authentication.currentUser
    if(currentUser == null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@ReferencesActivity, OnboardingActivity::class.java))
    } 
}
```

In OnboardingActivity I have the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding)

    val loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login)
    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
```

And finally in LoginActivity I have this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    // my_child_toolbar is defined in the layout file
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar))

    // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar and enable the Up button
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

Everything is displayed correctly, and the flow works as intended, except that when I click the back button in the LoginActivity toolbar, it gets back to RootActivity instead of OnboardingActivity.

I'm sure I forgot something, but what?

Comment: Be careful about the difference between "back" and "up" navigation. See https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for details.

Comment: `finish()` has removing current activity from a stack. Remove this line and all will be fine.

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thanks a lot @grabarz121
Please add your comment as an answer.